# Append a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following piece of code in a Wordpress site:

```
function myscript() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    define ('FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY', $upload_dir['baseurl'];
    echo bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/myscript.php?src=';
}
```

I'd like to append the `$upload_dir[baseurl]` with `/folder/` but can't seem to figure it out.

I've tried a couple of things, such as changing the 2nd line to:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir() . '/folder/';
```

Changing the 3rd line and adding above it:

```
$myscriptdir =  $upload_dir['baseurl'].'/folder';
define ('FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY', $myscriptdir);
```

And  simply changing the 3rd line to:

```
define ('FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY', $upload_dir['baseurl'].'/folder/');
```

But none of these works. Any help?

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm new to PHP.

Comment: Why aren't you closing bracket of `define(`.

Comment: sorry, yes the bracket is closed - i typed it wrong.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? Or did the closing bracket fix your issue?

Comment: No error, the script is not adding its files to the baseurl/folder/ directory, but simply to baseurl/

Comment: Are you actually outputting `FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this:

```
function myscript() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    $upload_dir['baseurl'] = $upload_dir['baseurl'].'/folder/';

    define ('FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY', $upload_dir['baseurl'];
    echo bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/myscript.php?src=';
}
```